# ARM without ALU how much for operations

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arm, alu

I had a problem on ARM Cortex M3 
with some functionality that requires multiply and divide natural numbers.
The point is: if it's possible to make calculations between 128 bits numbers? 
I need to know how many assembly operations need software emulate multiple two 32 numbers and divide two 32bits numbers and then I will calculate time consumption of my calculations.
I stuck with some calculation and I need help because maybe I have to change my uC to cortex M4 with hardware ALU.

Can You help me with this?

Given simple C code:

```
uint32_t var1 = 12304;
uint32_t var2 = 1892637198;
uint64_t result = var1*var2;
```

And objdump assembler:

```
   0:   b480            push    {r7}
   2:   b085            sub     sp, #20
   4:   af00            add     r7, sp, #0
        uint32_t var1 = 12304;
   6:   f243 0310       movw    r3, #12304      ; 0x3010
   a:   60fb            str     r3, [r7, #12]
        uint32_t var2 = 1892637198;
   c:   f645 230e       movw    r3, #23054      ; 0x5a0e
  10:   f2c7 03cf       movt    r3, #28879      ; 0x70cf
  14:   60bb            str     r3, [r7, #8]

        uint64_t result = var1*var2;
  16:   68fb            ldr     r3, [r7, #12]
  18:   68ba            ldr     r2, [r7, #8]
  1a:   fb02 f103       mul.w   r1, r2, r3
  1e:   460a            mov     r2, r1
  20:   f04f 0300       mov.w   r3, #0
  24:   e9c7 2300       strd    r2, r3, [r7]
```

So if I calculate for example multiple multiplying can I get whole instruction (because loading values into registers so plus 3 instruction for each load) or only multiplying (in this case 6 instruction)

Because multiplying two 128bits variable formatted as (x^5+x) where x is 32bits variable give me (a+b)(c+d) ab+ad+bc+bd 4 multiply (or 3 by using algorithms).
So if I should calculate 4*(3+3+6) or 4*(6+?+?).

Comment: How about posting some codes?

Comment: @Jake 'Alquimista' LEE - I Post simple example and equivalent assembly code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ARM Instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/CHDDIGAC.html)

This page contains all of the cycle counts per instruction for the ARM M-Series processor.  If you have the assembly code (which it sounds like you do?) then it should be easy enough to add up all of your cycles, multiply by 1/clock_freq and get your total time spent for different scenarios.

Comment: Based on that link, the M3 includes 32 bit multiply and divides, so no emulation required for those operations. For 128 bit operations, you'll need to implement extended precision math. I'm not sure if the advanced methods of doing this would be more efficient than emulating long hand multiplication and long hand division (similar to how a person does this with pencil and paper).

Comment: @rcgldr I known some math but what about Assembler? :)

Comment: One option for now, write the code in C, then have the compiler produce assembler code, then decide if you want to modify the assembler code.

Answer (score -1):

The another solution is to use systick to measure cycle count.

See this [link from ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka8713.html)

**Edit:** You can set Counter to max and force to re-load its counter value once it has reached to 0.

// Configure Systick
    *STRVR = 0xFFFFFF;  // max count
    *STCVR = 0;         // force a re-load of the counter value register
    *STCSR = 5;         // enable FCLK count without interrupt

You can read STCVR  reg which is a down register before and after function and then remove the overhead cycles (to read STCVR register).